# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (when using if statement inside 2 for each)

Tags: javascript

I keep getting typeError Cannot read properties of undefined from this code. The weird thing is yesterday, it was working perfectly.

here is the code:

```js
const products = [{
        id: "e43638ce-6aa0-4b85-b27f-e1d07eb678c6",
        image: "imgs/products/athletic-cotton-socks-6-pairs.jpg",
        name: "Black and Gray Athletic Cotton Socks - 6 Pairs",
        rating: {
            stars: 4.5,
            count: 87
        },
        priceCents: 1090,
    },
    {
        id: "15b6fc6f-327a-4ec4-896f-486349e85a3d",
        image: "imgs/products/intermediate-composite-basketball.jpg",
        name: "Intermediate Size Basketball",
        rating: {
            stars: 4,
            count: 127
        },
        priceCents: 2095
    }
];



const cart = [{
    productId: "156a1ze6-985s-78aze-5646q5sd-aze5q6s214ggh",
    quantity: 2,
}];


let matchingProduct;

cart.forEach((cartItem) => {
  let productId = cartItem.productId;

  products.forEach((product) => {


      if (product.id === productId) {
          matchingProduct = product
      }

  });

  console.log(matchingProduct)
```

Could you please help me to understand why this is happening.

Thank you.

I am confused and tried to identify the error. the only thing that I found is that for some reasons the if statement doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which line is producing the error?  Does the error indicate which property the code is attempting to read from `undefined`?  (Note that the code provided is producing an entirely different error when executed...)

Comment: I keep getting the error when I try to generate new HTML like this one.

document.querySelector('.js-delivery-date-choice').innerHTML=`<div class="delivery-date-title delivery-date-title-${matchingProduct.id}">Delivery date: Tuesday`

Apparently, matchingProduct.id is undefined

Comment: Your cart item's product id doesn't match anything in your products array. Your existing code here makes no references to any html.

Comment: @MassinissaaOuiddir accessing `matchingProduct.id` assumes that a product with a matching id was found, which it isn't in this case.

Comment: add this  });  above the console.log line.

Comment: @MassinissaaOuiddir: *"matchingProduct.id is undefined"* - If `matchingProduct` is `undefined` that would produce this error, but not if the `.id` property is `undefined`.  Though that's not the only thing on that line of code which **could** produce that error, so it's important to make sure you're not making an invalid assumption.  More to the point... That code **isn't in** the code you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you for your insights guys. I am sorry for my poor post. I am webdev beginner and very new to the website. in fact. it's my first post. 

Your help is very appreciated. You are right, no items from my cart match the products and I didn't check this simple detail. I need to take a break I guess.

Comment: What are you actually trying to even _do_ with those nested `forEach` calls?

Answer (score 1):

With your code, you try to check if `156a1ze6-985s-78aze-5646q5sd-aze5q6s214ggh` from `const cart` is in `const products`. `156a1ze6-985s-78aze-5646q5sd-aze5q6s214ggh` (`cart[0].productId`) is neither equal to `products[0].id` or `products[1].id`. Subsequently, no value is set to`let matchingProduct`, which gives you `undefined` as output.